# How to free GPU memory in OpenTK using C#

Tags: c#, opengl, memory-management, gpu, opentk

In order to show images in Fullscreen with 60 FPS and a stable framerate, I'm learning how to do that in OpenGL with C# (OpenTK library).

I've got a basic project running with a GameWindow class, that can upload images as textures to the gpu memory and show it with 60 FPS. My problem is that the gpu memory is never freed, when the process is finished. Only when I close the application, it is freed.

I've tried the most common suggestions like GL.DeleteTexture and calling GC manually a few times, but nothing seem to work. The gpu memory usage is increasing every time I start the GameWindow from the Windows Form.

Any suggestions how to manage the GPU memory in a better way? My application will be critical to gpu memory, as I want to load a lot of images (>1GB) in the gpu memory and display them with 60 FPS with good timings, where the CPU is quite unreliable in regard of stable framerate. And the stable framerate is essential for this.

Here's my example GameWindow class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenGLAnimation
{
    class OpenGLShow : GameWindow
    {
    #region --- Global Variables -------------------------------------
    public  bool            bRunning      = true;
    public  bool            bFinishedLoad = false;
    public  int             WorkTime      = 0;
    private Screen          Scrn;
    private List<int>       TextureList = new List<int>();
    private Thread          MainThread;
    #endregion

    #region --- Constructor ------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the Class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FilesPath">Directory path with all the images, that will be shown.</param>
    /// <param name="_Screen">Information about the screen, on which the images will be shown.</param>
    /// <param name="ScreenIndex">Index of the screen (first monitor = 0; second monitor = 1 ..</param>
    public OpenGLShow (Screen _Screen, DisplayDevice disp, int ScreenIndex = 1) : 
        base(_Screen.WorkingArea.Width, _Screen.WorkingArea.Height, OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.Default, "FBSScreen", GameWindowFlags.Fullscreen, disp)
    {
        Scrn         = _Screen;

        bFinishedLoad = false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region --- Event triggered functions ----------------------------
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs EvAr)
    {
        WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Hidden;
        WindowState  = WindowState.Fullscreen;
        VSync        = VSyncMode.On;

        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Scrn.WorkingArea.Width, Scrn.WorkingArea.Height);
        GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        Context.MakeCurrent(null);
        MainThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        MainThread.Start();
    }
    #endregion

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!bFinishedLoad) { Thread.Sleep(500); Console.WriteLine("Textures are loaded. Waiting.."); }

        MakeCurrent();
        int         index     = 0;
        int         MaxIndex  = TextureList.Count;
        Stopwatch   swRender  = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch   swSumTime = new Stopwatch();

        swSumTime.Restart();
        while (bRunning && TextureList.Count > 0)
        {
            swRender.Restart();

            if (index >= MaxIndex) { index = 0; }

            GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureList[index++]);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Polygon);
            GL.Color4(Color.White);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1); GL.Vertex2(-1, -1);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(-1,  1);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0); GL.Vertex2( 1,  1);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1); GL.Vertex2( 1, -1);
            GL.End();
            SwapBuffers();
            GL.Finish();

            Title = "FPS: " + Math.Round((decimal)1000 / swRender.ElapsedMilliseconds, 2) + "  |  Frame: " + index + "/" + MaxIndex;

            if (WorkTime > 0 && WorkTime < swSumTime.ElapsedMilliseconds) { Abort(); }
        }
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        bRunning = false;
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);     // unbind textures
        //foreach (int i in TextureList)                // doesn't free GPU memory
        //{
        //    GL.DeleteTexture(i);
        //    GL.DeleteBuffer(i);
        //}

        TextureList.Clear();
        Close();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        MainThread.Start();
    }

    private void AddTexture(string sPath)
    {
        int     tmpTexture = 0;
        Bitmap  bmp        = new Bitmap(sPath);

        GL.GenTextures(1, out tmpTexture);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tmpTexture);

        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bmpData.Width, bmpData.Height, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmpData.Scan0);

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

        TextureList.Add(tmpTexture);
    }

    public void LoadImages(string sPath)
    {
        List<string> Files = new List<string>();
        TextureList.Clear();

        if (File.Exists(sPath))
        {
            Files.Add(sPath);
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(sPath))
        {
            Files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(sPath));
        }

        foreach (string s in Files)
        {
            if (s.Contains(".png") || s.Contains(".bmp") || s.Contains(".jpg"))
            {
                AddTexture(s);
            }
        }

        bFinishedLoad = true;
    }
}
}
```

To test the Class, you can download the [OpenTK refs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTK/) with NuGet and just create a new Form with a button, that does the following

```
string filesPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures";
Screen[] scr = Screen.AllScreens;
OpenTK.DisplayDevice display = OpenTK.DisplayDevice.GetDisplay(OpenTK.DisplayIndex.First);

OpenGLAnimation.OpenGLShow gwForm = new OpenGLAnimation.OpenGLShow(scr[0], display, 0);
gwForm.WorkTime = 2000;            // if worktime = 0 then the images will be looped forever
gwForm.LoadImages(filesPath);   // load images as textures to GPU memory. Can be a png/bmp file or a directory with such files
gwForm.Run();
```

The essential part is basically the AddTexture(), DoWork() and Abort() functions where I upload the images to gpu memory, show them on a display and use Abort() to stop & finish up the process.

Comment: How do you measure GPU memory consumption? I doubt GC will have any effect on it, but at least when you delete the OpenGL context everything should be gone. Actually DeleteTexture should also free the memory. Other than that there is no way to control the memory usage of OpenGL.

Comment: I measure the memory consumption with the performance profiler of Visual Studio 2015 and also monitor it with Process Explorer in the GPU tab. Both show no effect what so ever, when I call DeleteTexture.
Strange, I guess I have to dig a bit further and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: Note, that glDeleteTexture will not delete the texture instantly. It just marks it for deletion if it is not used anywere. If you have the texture bound at that point, it will never be deleted.

Comment: @BDL: Also the OpenGL implementation is likely to keep around the memory allocation in anticipation that likely (a) new texture(s) with the same layout parameters may be allocated in the near future.

Comment: Does that mean, that the memory will be freed, when the old allocated memory is not used but new memory is requested for other purposes? In that case it should be fine, I guess.